# Don't prevent me from saving a project that doesn't build

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I constantly get this incredibly annoying prompt when I'm trying to save while my project won't build:

[image]

I don't care, I just want to save and I don't want to hit **Yes** every time.

How can I get rid of this annoying prompt?